# Complex analysis: What can be said about $f$ $c$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The problems reads:

$f$ is an entire function satisyfing

$$\lim_{r\to \infty}\,\sup_{|z|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{3/2}}= c\in[0,\infty).$$

What can be said about $f$ and $c$?

I'm not sure how to get started with this problem. I've been told that I might be able to use the proof of Liouville's theorem (similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)#Proof)) But I'm just not sure how.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, using that proof technique you should be able to show that $f(z) = az+b$ for some constants $a$ and $b$, and thus that $c=0$.

Comment: @Greg Martin. Thanks for the input, but I'm not entirely sure I get it. Wouldn't I have to assume that $f(z)$ is bounded? Replacing $|z|$ with $r$ and letting $r \rightarrow \infty$ gets me $c=0$, if $f(z)$ in bounded, right?